# detect where the bounding ball with bars should go next

Tags: javascript

so, i am making a simple game and wrote some code that detect the ball touching a bar and should bounce up.

and it do so except that it never change the position.

it start going left and up but it dose not go from left to right as the game suppose to do.

here is the code that handle the operation above

```
function checkWallColution(b) {
    const offset = b.offset();
    const oOffset = b.oldOffset;
    baroffset = getOffset(bar);

    const bSetting = {
        left: offset.x <= gOffset.x,
        right: offset.width + offset.x >= gOffset.x + gOffset.width,
        top: offset.y <= gOffset.y,
        bottom: offset.height + offset.y >= gOffset.height + gOffset.y,
        bar: offset.height + offset.y +10 >= baroffset.y && (offset.x >= baroffset.x && offset.x <= baroffset.right)
    }

    if (bSetting.bottom) {
        b.lost = true;
        return bSetting;
    }
    let top = offset.y;
    let left = offset.x;
    const adder = 1.3;

    if (bSetting.top) {
        if (offset.x < oOffset.x) {
            left += adder;

        } else left -= adder;
        top += adder;
    }else if (bSetting.left) {
        if (offset.y <= oOffset.y) {
            top -= adder;
        } else top += adder;
        left += adder;
    } else if (bSetting.right) {
        if (offset.y <= oOffset.y) {
            top -= adder;
        } else top += adder;


        if (offset.x <= oOffset.x) {
            left += adder;

        }else left -=adder;

    }
    if (!bSetting.top && !bSetting.bottom && !bSetting.left && !bSetting.right) {
        left -= adder;
        if (offset.y <= oOffset.y)
            top -= adder;
        else top += adder;
    }

    if (bSetting.bar) {
        if (offset.left < oOffset.left) {
            left += adder;
        } else left -= adder
        top-= adder;
    }

    b.style.top = top + "px";
    b.style.left = left + "px";
    return bSetting;
}

let startTimer = undefined;
function start() {
    startTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        let index = 0;
        while (index < balls.items.length) {
            const b = balls.items[index];
            const offset = b.offset();
            if (b.oldOffset === undefined)
                b.oldOffset = offset;
            const colSetting = checkWallColution(b);
            if (colSetting.lost) {
                balls.removeAt(index);
                continue;
            }

            b.oldOffset = b.offset();

            index++;
        }
        start();
    },
        1)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API